# Google Map place API request limit?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

As per my understanding,after the verification the quota limit increase to 1,00,000 requests per day for free of cost.But my doubt is if the requests cross the limit(1,00,000) then what will be the case?Does google charge for excess requests?If charged what will be the tariff? if it will not permit to excess more than 1,00,000 request per day then please say any alternate?how can we know that it exceeds the limit.

Comment: Yes, I have the same doubt lasting for few days, can any one from google maps team address this ASAP. Thanks

Comment: Have you read the official documentation on it? It is stated there what happens.

Comment: i checked in the below link https://developers.google.com/places/uplift.but i found no useful info

Answer (score 0):

If you are quota'd to 100,000 requests per day, requests over and above this will error out with an error stating that you are over quota. You can request more quota, at which point I will work with you to build a case to our management for why they should give you more quota, or you can license the API for additional quota by contacting our Sales team.

Comment: After adding payment details, I see two fields in the api console, free quota: 1000 and total quota: 100,000 now this confusing, will i be charged for queries above 1000 or not?

Comment: No, we only use the credit card to verify who you are, not to charge you for usage. Apologies for the confusing wording.